# How to run ammeter in low resistance?

Tags: current, electromagnetism, multimeter, battery-operated

I need to measure current in a small electromagnet powered off 3 x AAA batteries in series. [This](https://issuu.com/ortegarosas/docs/manual_ms8233c) is the manual for my multimeter. When I run this multimeter in series and try to find the current, the electromagnet doesn't work anymore. I suspect the internal resistance of the multimeter to be too high compared to my electromagnet (just a few coils of 20AWG magnet wire) so the electromagnet isn't getting enough voltage anymore. Is there a cheap/free solution for me to find the current in the electromagnet?

Comment: how much current are we approximately talking about?

Comment: AAA batteries still pack quite a punch, so if you practically short them, I'd still expect a couple Ampere flowing. Maybe you just broke your multimeter's fuse?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I can measure voltage just fine so it can't be the fuse. Maybe there is something wrong elsewhere in the multimeter?

Comment: there's a fuse in line only in current, not in voltage measurement mode. So this is not an indication of functionality.

Comment: Did you remember to move the plug to the "10A" socket (use the 10A range) to measure teh current? Internal resistance should be pretty low on that range.

Comment: @MarcusMüller does the voltmeter not go through the fuse? They are in the same plug.

Comment: @PeterZhu why should it? In voltmeter mode, the device has an enormous inner resistance, so no fuse will be needed.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Why should I use the 10A socket? I don't think 3 x AAA batteries will deliver anywhere close to 10A. Shouldn't I use something like the 200mA?

Comment: @PeterZhu Read Charles' answer. 10A probably has lower resistance. Also, you probably blew the fuse on the smaller setting. And yes, AAA will deliver high currents.

Comment: Because the 10A socket will have the lowest internal resistance. And decent AAA's like NiCds may surprise you with their current.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I just tried it with the 10A socket and setting, it still doesn't work. The meter still reads 0 and the electromagnet doesn't work.

Comment: I just checked the cheapest supermarket Zinc/air battery I found in the "nearly empty" bin. It gave me 5.4A.

Comment: Then it is possible you have blown the 10A fuse too.

Comment: Then something is broken with your multimeter, or your cables, or your coil. Let's assume you lose 1V in the ammeter (that's far higher than what you really lose, but let's act like that), then you'd still have a 3.5V drop across your coil. No coil in this world would then be an isolator. The most likely isolator here is definitely your ammeter's fuses.

Comment: Have you measured ohmic resistance of your coil? What is it? (hint: an electromagnet not doing any work doesn't "lose" energy, aside from ohmic resistance, when driven with DC)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Could you estimate how high the resistance of an average ammeter is?

Comment: @MarcusMüller The resistance of the coil is 0.2 ohms.

Comment: @PeterZhu there's no average ammeter. But it definitely would be in less than a 10 milliohms. Otherwise, P=I²R with I=10A would hurt.

Comment: well, \$\frac{4.5\,\text V}{0.2\,\Omega}=22.5\,\text A\$. Happily, the batteries won't allow this, because of their source impedance, which is what I **asked** you to measure by comparing voltage with and without load (see comments under answer). Also, 0.2 Ohm is something that requires very good contact when measuring. I'd guess that it should be lower if you had a proper measurement device and proper connectors for resistances of this order of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the 10A range. Set the meter to 10A and plug the red lead into the 10A jack. There are two fuses, one 10A fuse for the 10A range and one 250mA fuse for the lower current ranges. You may have blown the fuse for the lower ranges. The fuse replacement instructions are on the last page.

Comment: :) thanks for picking up on this! Definitely, "just a few windings of 20AWG" will easily blow a fuse (which pretty certainly is "thinner" than 20AWG) rated 250mA.

Comment: So I still have a few questions. Does the voltmeter not go through the fuse because I can still measure voltage just fine on that socket? Will the batteries really output more than 0.25A?

Comment: @PeterZhu you've gotten answers to that in the comments. If you don't believe what we write, why are you asking?

Comment: No, usually, the voltmeter setting will not be fused. That would be nonsensical, because a voltmeter has very high internal resistance.

Comment: Yes, fresh AAA batteries easily produce more than 5A.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sorry, I didn't mean it that way, I was just surprised. I just tried it with the 10A socket and setting, it still doesn't work. The meter still reads 0 and the electromagnet doesn't work.

Comment: Have you verified the voltage of your battery? 0A is highly unlikely, because a magnet will not stop conducting completely, just because you decrease the voltage.

Comment: @MarcusMüller My batteries work fine if I remove the ammeter.

Comment: @PeterZhu that was not my question.

Comment: @PeterZhu how high, according to *your multimeter* is the voltage of the unloaded batteries, and how high is it under load?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I the voltage without the load is 4.8V and is 4.5V with load.

Comment: wow! that's a low source impedance for batteries. Yes, these will easily deliver a lot of current. Let's look at this, and assume your 0.2 Ohm measurement was right, as well as the load measurement (with the batteries connected to the magnet): at 4.5V over 0.2 Ohm, 22.5 A flow. You just blew your 10A fuse.

Comment: really, these batteries should be getting **hot** at these currents, very quickly. Are you sure you measure 4.5V with the coil attached?

Comment: @MarcusMüller It was fluctuating around 4.4 and 4.5. The batteries does not seem hot at all even after around 1 minute of running. The measure of resistance was from perfect contact and I am making a Beakman's motor, so it is only in contact half of the time.

Comment: @PeterZhu aaah so the coil is constantly excerting force, ok, then the coils resistance is higher. that's a good thing, because you don't have to watch for fires :)

Comment: Still, I'm afraid you blew at least the 250mA fuse, and probably the 10A fuse, too.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Is there some easy way I can test if the fuse is really broken?

Comment: It's broken. when nearly shorting batteries across the fuse, no current flows. What better test can there be???